# Do I need to replace the thermostat wiring leading to my boiler?

Tags: wiring, thermostat, furnace, boiler

I have a boiler in an old building with four different apartments. There are two thermostats that call for heat from the boiler, and valves that direct the hot water to the respective part of the building that is calling for heat. On the east side of the building there is no radiant heat.

If I jump the boiler at the control panel for the east side of the building, the boiler turns on and sends heat to the east side. If I jump the boiler from the thermostat for the east side, the boiler does not turn on.

Would this indicate that there is a problem with the wiring? Would I need to re-run the thermostat wire?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: that sounds about right to me. but if you can locate the damage you could just repair that.

Comment: Stack exchange allows/encourages answering your own questions. Since you have pretty much the right answer IN your question, go ahead and put it in as an answer. Yes, run new wire - if you do, consider more modern wire (you likely have old red-white 2-wire, and the modern fancy-pants things use many more wires - if going to the bother of running new wire, might as well make it ready if the thermostat is ever upgraded.